# How to upload profile image from URL using Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, image-uploading, portlet

I have tried something like that, however I am pretty sure that it is a wrong way.

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(pictureUrl));
long portraitId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(Image.class.getName());
Image portraitImage = ImageLocalServiceUtil.createImage(portraitId);
DataBufferByte data   = (DataBufferByte) bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
portraitImage.setTextObj(data.getData());
Image image = ImageLocalServiceUtil.addImage(portraitImage);
```

Some people told me that I should use Document and media portlet, but it is used on back-end?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer and it perfectly works for me:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new URL(pictureUrl));
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", os);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
byte[] bytes = FileUtil.getBytes(is);
UserLocalServiceUtil.updatePortrait(userId, bytes);
```